# Jquery function response is undefined

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a project and I recently came across this strange Jquery behaviour!

> Code Snippet

```
$("#form_1").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    response =  sendform('form_1', '../php/signup-01.php', 'POST', '');
    console.log(response.responseText);
});
```

> sendform()

```
function sendform(id, location, method, extrapars) {
    response = $.ajax({
        url : location ,
        data : $("#"+id).serialize() + extrapars ,
        cache : false ,
        processData : false  ,
        type : method ,
        success : function (successmsg) {
            return successmsg;

                }
            });
    return response;
}
```

So basically I'm trying to send some form data through a pre-defined function, but when I try to log it response in my console it says `Undefined`. I know that this is an JS Object, so I even  tried using `Console.log(response[responseText])`.

When I try to log the complete object, `Console.log(response)`, Its something LIKE

```
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ ( fn )
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )
pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ ( obj )
readyState: 4
responseText: "Unused OTP in DB!"
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ ( map )
statusText: "OK"
then: ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )
__proto__: Object
```

So any help with that would be helpful for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is because `$.ajax` returns `deferred` which is a JQuery kind of `promise` compatible with promises.

Comment: SO what does that mean?

Comment: You might need to use async/await combo because response is returned far before success callback is called

Comment: Take a look here: https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax/

Comment: Indifferent. The ajax request is asynchronous. You can't disregard this. If you are not familiar with asynchronous behavior, you should start getting this right in your mind.

Comment: Add `async: false` in the `$.ajax` request, but it's not a good practice. Follow the @ZorgoZ suggestion and learn the async behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this. Indifferent to how the `$.ajax` method's result will be processed, you can further rely on JQuery, so you can forget callbacks.

```js
function sendform(id, location, method, extrapars) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : location ,
        data : $("#"+id).serialize() + extrapars ,
        cache : false ,
        processData : false  ,
        type : method
    });
}
```

Now, as for the usage, you can either rely on the new fashioned `async/await`:

```js
$("#form_1").submit(asnyc function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response =  await sendform('form_1', '../php/signup-01.php', 'POST', '');
      console.log(response);
   } catch(ex) {
      // handle error
   }
});
```

Or you can use the JQquery way:

```js
$("#form_1").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
      sendform('form_1', '../php/signup-01.php', 'POST', '')
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // handle error      
      });      
});
```

*Deferred* is promises compatible, thus they are `then`-able also.